Is there a function in pypdf to get the page number of a field? (Python)
I'm trying to find an attribute or function that will return the page number/index of a field that I pass as an argument. E.g. get_field_page_number(field_name) -> int
I want to be able to get a page number so that I can use update_page_form_field_values()
I've been looking in the pypdf documentation, but I have had no luck. I think in PyPDF2 there is supposedly a field.get('/P') function.
There is a get_destination_page_number() but it seems like that is for something else.
I have also found get_pages_showing_field() which looks like it's what I'm searching for, but I don't know how to use it. It says it is asking for a field, so I have tried this block of code:
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter
import pypdf

reader = PdfReader(input_path) # path to PDF
writer = PdfWriter()
fields = reader.get_fields()
for field in fields:
    pages = writer.get_pages_showing_field(field)
    print('Field Name: ', field)
    print('Pages field is in: ', pages)

This results in a ValueError: field type is invalid error, however.
I have also tried using form_fields_dict = reader.get_form_text_fields() and iterating through those, to the same results.

Have you tried reader.get_pages_showing_field() as documented? https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/forms.html#identify-pages-where-fields-are-used

As it turns out, reader.get_pages_showing_field() is not needed. What you need to look at are the annotations.
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter
import pypdf

reader = PdfReader(input_path) # path to PDF
writer = PdfWriter()
fields = reader.get_fields()

for field_name, field in fields.items():
    pages = []
    for page_num, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
        annotations = page.get('/Annots', [])
        for annot in annotations:
            if annot.get_object().get('/T') == field_name:
                pages.append(page_num + 1)  # Page numbers are 1-based
                print('Field Name:', field_name)
                print('\tPages field is in:', pages)

